# Creación de teclado QWERTY con materialize

Tags: css, materialize, grid

Buenas tardes,

Me gustaría saber si ésta es la forma correcta de realizar un teclado con botones mediante materialize y si uso correctamente el grid ya que no me aparece del todo centrado.

Otro problema que tengo es que al reducir la resolución se me cambian los botones de posición, ¿hay alguna manera de que no se vea afectado utilizando el grid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col 10 offset-s2">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Q</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">W</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">E</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">R</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">T</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Y</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">U</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">I</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">O</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">P</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col 10 offset-s2">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">A</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">S</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">D</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">F</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">G</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">H</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">J</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">K</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">L</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Ñ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col 7 offset-s3">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Z</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">X</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">C</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">V</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">B</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">N</a>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">M</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Os dejo el codepen del documento:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/manufdezginzo/full/NaJpmx/) 
Gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo mas parecido que puedo conseguir respecto a tu pregunta. Usando div en lugar de enlaces, con aspecto de botón.

Aqui te dejo el código:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 offset-s1 center">
          <div class="col s1 green btn">Q</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">W</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">E</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">R</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">T</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">Y</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">U</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">I</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">O</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">P</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 offset-s1 center">
          <div class="col s1 green btn">A</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">S</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">D</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">F</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">G</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">H</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">J</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">K</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">L</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">Ñ</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s10 offset-s3">
          <div class="col s1 green btn">Z</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">X</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">C</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">V</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">B</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">N</div>
          <div class="col s1 green btn">M</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```